# Dilettante replaced by Encounter-atk replacing feat?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, powers, half-elf

I'm trying to create a Blackguard multiclass-vampire. One of the multiclass-vampire feats called "Thirst for Blood" allows you to "Choose one of your encounter attack powers that has a level. You lose that power and gain blood drinker" - however, the only leveled encounter power a Blackguard has is Dread Smite, and I don't want to lose it.

The Half-Elf Dilettante ability allows you to choose an encounter power from other class' at-wills. Now, I can't see anything in the rules that wouldn't allow me to replace that power with the Blood Drinker power - thus gaining it while keeping Dread Smite. Since the feat description of Thirst for Blood does not state that it must be a class encounter power, merely an encounter power with a level, surely the Dilettante level 1 power must qualify?

The official DnD 4e character creator won't let me select it to replace, but I'd like to hear what your interpretations of the rules are. It seems to me as though it should be allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You cannot trade away your Dilettante power with Thirst for Blood.**

From PHB1, pg27, Half-Elves (*emphasis mine*):

> **Dilettante:** At 1st level, you choose an *at-will* power from a class different from yours. You can use that power *as* an encounter power.

The key here is that the power you get from Half-Elf Dilettante is a level 1 *at-will* power, not an encounter power. Half-Elf Dilettante only lets you *use* that power once per encounter, but the power itself still *is* an at-will power, and therefore not eligible to trade away with Thirst for Blood.